# Finding the dimension and basis for an orthogonal complement.

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I'm working on the following problem in preparation for a test.

> Let $v_1=(1,2,3,4)$ and $V$ be the subspace of $\mathbb R ^4$  described $V=span(v_1)$.
>
> a) What is the dimension of $V^⊥$, the orthogonal complement of $V$?
>
> b)Find a basis for $V^⊥$.

I'm honestly pretty confused with linear algebra, the course I'm taking skims by it quickly and I haven't been able to understand what's going on. Anyway, here's my solution so far.

For part a, the dimension of $V$ is 4 since the vector $v_1=(1,2,3,4)$ is 4-dimensional. The orthogonal complement, $V^\perp$ must have the same dimension. Therefore, $V^\perp$ is also 4-dimensional.

Now, for part b.
$$ [1,2,3,4][a,b,c,d]^T=0 \\ \text{Choose} \ \  a=1, b=1, c=-1, d=0. \ \ \text{Then} \\ [1,2,3,4][1,1,-1,0]^T = 1(1)+2(1)+3(-1)+4(0)=0. \\ \therefore [1,1,-1,0]^T \ \text{forms a basis for} \ V. \\ \text{Next, choose} \ \ a=0, b=2, c=0, d=-1. \ \ \text{Then}, \\ [1,2,3,4][0,2,0,-1]^T=1(0)+2(2)+3(0)+4(-1)=0 \\ \therefore [0,2,0,-1] \ \ \text{also forms a basis for} \ V. $$

First, is my work correct up until here? Second, I know I need to now take these and find a basis for $V^\perp$, but I'm not sure where to begin with that.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Hi Kosta, thank you for asking your question very clearly! There are definitely some confusions that you'll want to clear up. Here are some true statements that you should work towards understanding: (1) The dimension of $V$ is $1$, not $4$; (2) the dimension of $V^\perp$ is $4-1=3$, not $4$; (3) both $[1,1,-1,0]$ and $[0,2,0,-1]$ are elements of $V^\perp$, not of $V$; (4) knowing that a vector is in a vector space is not the same as that vector being a basis for the vector space. I suggest starting by stating the *exact definitions* of: dimension, orthogonal complement, and basis.